# Some geographical names

Tags: knowledge, geography

A certain country of the world was named after a person.
Its capital was named after another, different person.

The given name (first name) of the first person mentioned above **is identical to** the surname (family or last name) of the second person mentioned above.

Identify the country, the capital, and the two people referred to.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The country was

> **Rhodesia**, named after Cecil Rhodes.

Its capital,

> **Salisbury**, was named after Robert Cecil, Marquess of Salisbury.

Comment: I'm curious how you found this.

Comment: @msh210 There's a helpful [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_named_after_people) on Wikipedia :)

Answer (score 2):

> Country: San Marino; Capitol City: San Marino; Person: Dalmatian stone-cutter named Marino. [Source](https://www.cityofsanmarino.org/government/history_of_san_marino_/index.php)

Comment: I almost went with this, but didn't think it fit the given name portion of the question, only the surname portion?

Comment: It seems the city and country were named after the same person. I can't tell whether Marino was his given name or his surname, but I don't see any indication that it was both.

Comment: @TCooper I mean they both work.

Comment: @TCooper Nevermind niether one works lol

Comment: @msh210 Oh, I never noticed that you said surname

Answer (score 2):

> Country: The United States of America;
>  Named after: Amerigo Vespucci;
>  Capital Named After: George Washington

Answer (score -1):

This might be stretching a bit but

> El Salvador, the capital of which is San Salvador, both referring to Jesus (The Savior and Holy Savior, respectively). While technically not a surname, by stretching the definition, Jesus can have a last name of Christ.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Please note that the question says that the first name and the surname in question are the same word.